# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia Obs Studio Screen Flickering GT1030

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, screen, flicker, obs-studio

I am using Nvidia GT1030 with OBS Studio running Ubuntu 16.04. When trying to record with OBS Studio, the screen is flickering. The same using other recording software - Kazam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out the Nvidia 384 driver has a bug. To disable OBS Studio flickering go to Nvidia settings - OpenGL settings - uncheck Allow Flipping. Close Nvidia settings.

[image]

Reference: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjQDSZUdKXE)

Comment: When it's on I get horrible flickering in my recordings. When it's off I get horrible tearing on my monitor. Isn't there any way to solve both? I have Nvidia 435.21 driver.

Comment: It applies to the 384 driver only.